# Firebase.setandroidcontext(getApplicationContext()) not working in application oncreate()

Tags: java, android, firebase

//android manifest

```
<application

    android:name = ".myapp"
    android:allowBackup = "true"
    android:icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label = "@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl = "true"
    android:theme = "@style/AppTheme" >

</application>
```

//class extended from Application

```
public class myapp extends android.app.Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(getApplicationContext());

}
```

Still giving error :You need to set the Android context using Firebase.setAndroidContext() before using Firebase.

Comment: pass `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 2):

Confirm you have this dependency on `build.grad` (Module:app)

```
 dependencies {
            implementation  'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(getApplicationContext());
```

into this:

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
```

more info here:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html

---

Also you are using a very old firebase version, it is better to upgrade to the latest version to be able to use the new features.

> In the new SDK, it's no longer necessary to call Firebase.setAndroidContext() so you can remove it from your code

https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android

Answer (score 0):

This is used in the very older version of firebase, Would suggest you to use the latest update (current version is 15.0.0).

Still, if you want to keep it as it is, you can change the code as given below,

> Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

instead of

> Firebase.setAndroidContext(getApplicationContext());